# Implicit Differentiation: Proving a point is perpendicular at a certain point on two interesecting tangents.

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, tangent-line

Given the following question:

Consider the curves C1 and C2 defined as follows;

C1 : xy = 4 , x > 0
C2 : y^2 - x^2 = 2 , x > 0

Let P(a,b) be a unique point where the curves C1 and C2 intersect. Show that the tangent C1 at P is perpendicular to the tangent to C2 at P.

I used implict differentiation to find the derivatives of both curves, with dy/dx = -y/x and dy/dx = x/y.

The solution provided shows multiplying the two derivatives together, netting a result of -1. Then "Therefore, the result follows".

Why is multiplying the derivatives the correct process and where do I take the answer to net the solution?

Comment: y=ax+b and y=cx+d are perpendicular iff ac=-1. That's a known theorem.